# c# System.OverflowException

Tags: c#, math, long-integer

So this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many numbers are you going to enter?");

    long num = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    long[] nums = new long[num];
}
```

When I enter 10000000000 for "num" I get

> "System.OverflowException   Arithmetic operation resulted in an
>   overflow."

What do i do to fix it?

Comment: I'd start by catching it.

Comment: This is some 80 GB of memory. Only 64-bit processes can handle this.

Comment: The number you are trying to use goes above Int32.MaxValue and you cannot create an array that big.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you are trying to allocate *a lot* of memory, since calling the long array constructor, actually already frees the memory you requested. A `long` is 64 bits, so 8 bytes. 8 bytes * 10000000000 = 80 GB of memory. That's too much.

The maximum length of an array in C# is `int.MaxValue`, which is 2,147,483,647 (16GB using a `long`), assuming you have enough memory.

Answer (score 9):

Your code overflows because the maximum size for an array in C# is `Int32.MaxValue`, which equals to 2147483647. You can see hints to that in the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,1855928543a94112), and it is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Array(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the maximum size of an Array is 2 gigabytes (GB). In a
>   64-bit environment, you can avoid the size restriction by setting the
>   enabled attribute of the configuration element (`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>` introduced in .NET 4.5) to true in the run-time
>   environment. However, the array will still be limited to a total of 4
>   billion elements, and to a maximum index of 0X7FEFFFFF (2146435071) in any given
>   dimension (0X7FFFFFC7 (2147483591) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte
>   structures).